# Why does Docker on Windows CMD fail for bash script?

Tags: python, windows, docker, fastapi

I've got a Dockerfile containerizing a Python FastAPI application that works on my Mac with this final CMD statement:

```
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

However, when I try to run the Dockerfile on a Windows machine that has Docker installed, it can't run/find the startup.sh script. I have to change the CMD to this:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--reload", "--workers", "1", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Any suggestions about why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Incorrect line endings on the shell script?

Comment: This seems like a stretch as the startup.sh script runs within the context of the Linux environment provided inside the Docker container.

Comment: If checking out the files on the Windows host checks them out with CR+LF line endings, `COPY`ing the script into a Linux-based image will not change it to LF-only Unix line endings.  That would make the "shebang" line look like `#!/bin/sh\r`, which would result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `startup.sh` file permissions on the Windows machine and make sure that it's executable.

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to do that. I work on a Mac and don't have ready access to a Windows machine to try things out. For example, I didn't even know Windows had executable file permissions.
Plus, I'm confused by this as the Docker container is running Linux, so the startup.sh file is running within that context.